# Dynamic api change

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

hello this is my first question, I wanted to create a dynamically changing link api based on e.target with select. I need the option value to be added to api as a number. I tried to use parseInt but unsuccessfully. the first time I get the message: Parameter 'matchday' is expected to be an integer in the range 1-46. After choosing another option, everything starts loading as it should.

Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Fixtures = ({ fixtures, getFixtures, loading }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getFixtures();
  }, [getFixtures]);

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    getFixtures(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleOnChange}>
        <option value="1">Matchday 1</option>
        <option value="2">Matchday 2</option>
      </select>
    </>
  );
};


export const getFixtures = matchday => dispatch => {
  dispatch(startFetchingFixtures());
  const getFixturesUrl = matchday =>
    `http://api.football-data.org//v2/competitions/2021/matches?matchday=${matchday}`;
  fetch(getFixturesUrl(matchday), {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": "..."
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => response.matches)
    .then(matches => dispatch(fetchedFixtures(matches)));
};
```

Comment: I see not `parseInt` in your example. Is it the example that works? Can you provide the broken code?

Comment: It works correctly. The issue is that on the first time you have propably an undefined value instead of a integer in range 1-46. Once you run onChange it gets proper value added.
Also, you call getFixtures() without any value on component mount but it should have a start value, let it be 1.

Comment: This example works when you select the option from select again, but sets value to string each time.  I didn't send parseInt in this example because it doesn't work on e.target.value

Comment: Try to not leave getFixtures() empty in the component mount effect and I believe this will solve your problem?

Comment: thank you Damian that was what I needed